# Django Permission Denied on Socket File

Tags: nginx, centos7, django

I'm trying to setup Django to run via NGINX on a Centos 7 server, however I seem to be encountering a non-stop barrage or problems. The main one that I am encountering now is that NGINX is giving me a permission denied error on the socket file. I've gone through every SO post and blog post I can find about the issue but nothing has worked. Can anyone help point out what I am doing wrong:

Currently here is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
    listen 80;
        server_name IPADDRESS;

        location = favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/user_name/project_name;
        }

    location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/var/uwsgi/project_name.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my uwsgi config file:

```
[uwsgi]
project = project_name
username = user_name
base = /home/%(username)

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

uid = %(username)
socket = /var/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(username):nginx
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
```

And here is my uwsgi.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /var/uwsgi; chown user_name:nginx /var/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My access logs are always printing something similar to the following (slight adjustments based on the socket file location and if there is 1 or 3 /'s after 'unix':

```
2016/06/14 15:54:48 [crit] 3073#0: *1 connect() to unix:///var/uwsgi/project_name.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: FROMIPADDRESS, server: IPADDRESS, request: "GET /events/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///var/uwsgi/project_name.sock:", host: "IPADDRESS"
```

Comment: Check permissions of socket and ALL of it's parents

Comment: srw-rw-rw-. 1 user_name nginx 0 Jun 14 15:53 /var/uwsgi/tackle_box.sock